# What is the cost/overhead of defining a type?

Tags: c++, types

Is there any runtime cost or overhead for having defined too many types in C++? For example, is there any difference at all between these two piece of code:

```
int main()
{
    int x, y;
    double fx, fy;

    return 0;
}
```

And:

```
template<typename T>
struct Point
{ 
    T x, y;
};

int main()
{
    Point<int> p;
    Point<double> fp;

    return 0;
}
```

Imagine a code which has many templated types, so that at compile time it generates even more concrete types: is it going to have any impact at runtime? My main concern is about static memory consumption.

Comment: Types are for people and compilers, not executables. Unless defining the types has *specific* overhead (like RTTI), there won't be a mention of them left in your program.

Comment: A question to which the real, and easy, answer is 'benchmark it and see' is not much of a question. :P

Comment: This might give you some insight: https://godbolt.org/g/B3ALjd

Comment: @Gerhardh even if the code example is in C++, the question is for both languages. You can easily write PointInt and PointFloat structures and the question remains the same: do type definition have overhead?

Comment: Often people are too trigger-happy with the C/C++ tags, but in this case I think it's pretty simple: if you want to ask about C, then don't use C++ specific concepts in the question. Your question opens by asking about C++ and places specific emphasis on templates, so that's C++ only.

Comment: I would recommend you to check it by yourself using https://godbolt.org

It is a Compiler Explorer which works really well for these cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a typical implementation, types without a vtable are virtually free - they cease to exist completely at compile time, where member access is transformed into moves from/to memory with the relevant offsets.

Types *with* a vtable (so, stuff with `virtual` methods) do have a O(number_of_types) cost in static memory consumption, namely each type will have to have a separate vtable/RTTI data, plus the data needed by `dynamic_cast` to navigate complex class hierarchies; in a typical implementation, you may estimate this cost in something like 1 pointer per `virtual` method + 1 pointer to RTTI information + the size of the mangled class name + a handful of pointers connecting the data structures for `dynamic_cast`. (This besides the cost of the vtable pointer in each *instance* of such types)

Comment: If the override called is always known, devirtualisation might result in the overhead of virtual types being elided too, right?

Comment: @underscore_d: in line of principle I'd say yes, although that requires a "smart enough" compiler/linker couple, and still I guess that such an optimization would probably work only in really easy situations (e.g. the class hierarchy is *never* used polymorphically). Still, I never performed such a test because generally it's not of great interest - usually if I have a class hierarchy with `virtual` methods it's because at least in some place I use its objects polymorphically (and the overhead is quite small anyway).

Comment: All true. Perhaps (IIRC) the `final` specifier might also help with devirtualisation. And yeah, it's probably not very common for this to be possible, but it might happen sometimes. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as types in the machine code (apart from the special case of RTTI). Therefore declaring types does not create any overhead.

Your examples are identical since both of them will result in a program that does exactly nothing, with no memory allocated. The variables aren't used by the program so they will get optimized away.

Comment: Would the downvoter explain their insight for the rest of us? I guess it makes assumptions about what a compiler will do, but those assumptions sound reasonable, and I think the poster has enough reputation to say with confidence.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking the compiler is not _required_ by the standard to implement utter basic optimization techniques. It is just happens that every compiler in the known world does this, or otherwise nobody would use them.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for your answer. Please consider that my code does nothing just because I've not been creative enough, so imagine whatever you like before the `return 0`. The focus of my question was about the *type definition* itself, not much on the usage of those defined types.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 Yes I understand that and the first sentence of the answer answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Simple usually have no cost at all. As mentioned before, there are some that might incur some runtime costa, like vtables or RTTI, but this is not guaranteed when the optimisation kicks in. Such questions are best resolved by actually testing the problem at hand.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/g/g8tMcn) you can see that your example generates identical code in both cases, even without optimisation.

Comment: Well, not __quite__ identical.