# What is the correct exception to throw when a method is called at an inappropriate time?

Tags: c++, exception

I have a class which exposes a method which should be called a certain number of times by the user of the class. The amount of times the method is to be called is agreed upon via an `int` parameter during object construction. Thus, while calling it too few times could be due to the caller deciding to cancel the operation for whatever reason, calling it too often clearly qualifies as a programming error, i.e. `std::logic_error`. I was wondering whether there is a more concrete exception to be thrown in this situation, such as `std::domain_error`. [This page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/domain_error) on cppreference.com says `std::domain_error` is thrown in:

> [...] situations where the inputs are outside of the domain on which an operation is defined

, which appears to match the use-case. However, I am asking because I am unsure whether a method call qualifies as "input" in this context. What exception should be thrown in this situation?

Comment: Why not use own exceptions?

Comment: ... which you can derive from `std::logic_error`.

Comment: Would you really bring an additional type into existence to account for a programming error that could be explained perfectly in a `what`-string of an existing exception type?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't cost any money. Plus, you can catch on a custom type, not on a custom string.

Comment: But perhaps you are opposed to it because what you really mean is to `assert`.

Comment: @Zyl definitely yes. Do you expect people to parse `what`-string if they want to catch this specific error?

Comment: "Would you really bring an additional type into existence..." absolutely yes. Types are great to convey meaning to the user. And isnt that what you ask for? Use a `you_called_me_too_often_error`

Comment: @freakish No. I expect them to read the string and not release a program with a programming error into the wild. Why have a catch-clause on something that only happens due to programming errors?

Comment: @Zyl so you want to write programs in an unfriendly way. That's your choice, bro.

Comment: To not lose track of the original question entirely: would you recommend to derive from `std::logic_error` or `std::domain_error`?

Comment: if you inherit from a standard exception type then users can catch a `logic_error`, though if you use some custom exception type then users can distinguish between all other `logic_error`s and exceptions thrown because of called too often. Btw, exceptions that can possibly only appear in a buggy program are sometimes unavoidable, but often there are other ways to catch the mistake at compile time already

Comment: Why have a catch clause due to programming errors? Because my specific app and domain works well with that error handling methodology, regardless of what some patronising library author thinks. Acting condescending to consumers of code doesn't make your library more usable, only puts it on the "replace asap" backlog item.

Comment: I have thought a bit about `assert`. It doesn't make sense here afaik because if I was to release a binary build in release-mode that wouldn't help the caller whatsoever. I think I see how a custom exception type makes sense here. Thanks. I will derive from `std::logic_error` to be safe, since noone seems to know the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the correct exception to throw when a method is called at an inappropriate time?

`std::logic_error`, preferably a struct/class deriving therefrom.

```cpp
struct PixelOverflowException : public std::logic_error {
    PixelOverflowException() : std::logic_error("Cannot accept further pixels: resampled image is already complete.") {}
};
```

Deriving can be useful even for runtime exceptions (programming errors) because:

- it will be easier to write tests checking the code's behavior in misuse scenarios.
- if the caller wants to check for a specific exception for whatever reason, they'll be able to do so as well.
- doing so has no cost. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44901257/593146

> std::domain_error

`std::domain_error` is a specific kind of `std::logic_error` that applies to situations where an operation is *possible in theory, but not in practice*. For example, a file format for photos might encode width and height as a 32-bit unsigned integer, meaning up to 4294967296 (if the encoded value is -1-biased) times 4294967296 = ‭18446744073709551616‬ pixels. A naive implementation of a decoder for such image format might be constrained to certain widths and heights, for example due to performing calculations involving width and height that will overflow long before the maximum width and height values occur.

```cpp
uint32_t numPixels = width * height; // will overflow for width and height = 65536.
```

In such cases, the decoder should throw an exception deriving from `std::domain_error` instead of blindly engaging in undefined behavior: the file can theoretically be decoded, but the specific implementation is unable to do so.

`std::domain_error` is different from `std::logic_error` in that an implementation which does not need to throw it is without a doubt conceivable, if only in theory if need be.

To emphasize, both exceptions hint at an error on the caller's side, and `std::domain_error` does not necessarily indicate that an implementation is of poor quality or incomplete: the set of accepted inputs might be constrained on purpose for reasons of performance, usability or scope.